# Cannot process argument transformation on parameter

Tags: powershell, arguments

I declared an array of tuples as follows:

```
 [System.Tuple[string,string][]] $files = @()
```

And I have the following workflow:

```
Workflow Perform-Download
{
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Tuple[string,string][]] $Files
    )
    ForEach -Parallel ($file in $Files)
    {
        Parallel{Save-File -Url $file.Item1 -DestinationFolder $file.Item2}
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
Perform-Download -Files $files
```

But I get the following error:

```
Perform-Download : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Files'. Cannot convert the 
"System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String][]" value of type "System.Tuple`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]][]" to type "System.Tuple".
At line:1 char:26
+ Perform-Download -Files $files
+                          ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Perform-Download], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Perform-Download
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leveraging what What Would Be Cool wrote, I tried the following. Basically `$Files` is passed as an `[array]` then it's typecasted to a Tuple.
I created a dummy `Save-File` which only writes the parameters to the output.

I'm not sure why the Tuple can't be passed as a parameter directly, you might have found a bug.

```
$files = @([System.Tuple]::Create("Flinstone","Rubble"), [System.Tuple]::Create("Simpsons","Flanders"))
function Save-File 
{
    Param ($URL, $DestinationFolder)
    Write-output ("{0} {1}" -f $URL, $DestinationFolder)    
}
Workflow Perform-Download
{
    Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [array] $Files
    )

    $Files = [System.Tuple[string,string][]] $Files
    ForEach -Parallel ($file in $Files)
    {
        Parallel{Save-File -Url $file.Item1 -DestinationFolder $file.Item2}
    }
}

Perform-Download -Files $files
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in a simple script:

```
param([System.Tuple[string,string][]]$files)

foreach ($file in $files) {
    [console]::WriteLine("Item1: {0}, Item2: {1}", $file.Item1, $file.Item2)
}
```

Then setting up the data and calling the script.

```
PS C:\data> $fileList = @([System.Tuple]::Create("Flinstone","Rubble"), [System.Tuple]::Create("Simpsons","Flanders"))

PS C:\data> .\soTuple.ps1 -files $fileList
Item1: Flinstone, Item2: Rubble
Item1: Simpsons, Item2: Flanders
```

See this article on [using Tuples in PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/09/02/using-a-tuple-in-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I already know that if I use a function instead of a workflow the script works. I just don't understand why it doesn't work with a workflow